# How do set theorists view this issue?

Tags: set-theory, philosophy

Since the question has changed significantly over the course of last few days, it was suggested to modify it in that light. I have removed those parts which aren't directly related to the main question, as it currently stands now. The current question is mostly just what I wrote in the "Edit:" in the previous version, along with few simplifications and small corrections.

The statement $(**)_1$ was mentioned in the answer (by Noah Schweber). Suppose that a hierarchy such as that in $(**)_1$ exists. Now consider the plausibility argument below of $(**)_1$ being "possibly" true.

Suppose that such a $\omega_1+1$ length hierarchy exists and that the $\omega_1$-point of such a hierarchy is the function $g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Now for any point $\alpha<\omega_1$ we denote the function at the point $\alpha$ as $f_\alpha:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Write "$f_1$ eventually dominates $f_2$" as $f_1>f_2$. Now whenever we have $\alpha<\beta<\omega_1$, we also have $f_\alpha < f_\beta$. Furthermore we have $g>f_\alpha$ for all $\alpha<\omega_1$.

Now we want to define a  collection of sets $C_i$ (where $i \in \omega$) such that they partition all limit values below $\omega_1$. Meaning all the $C$'s are disjoint and their union is the set of all limit values below $\omega_1$. We define the set $C_n$ (for arbitrary $n$) in the following manner. A given limit element $\alpha<\omega_1$ belongs to $C_n$ if and only if:
$$g(n-1) \le f_\alpha(n-1)$$ 
$$g(x) > f_\alpha(x) \,\,\,\, for \,\, all \,\, x\ge n$$ 
For the definition of $C_0$ we drop the line $g(n-1) \le f_\alpha(n-1)$ and just consider the second line.

Now we want to consider two separate scenarios.

**(1)** 
For all values $i \in \omega$ the least upper bound of values in $C_i$ is strictly less than $\omega_1$. Symbolically we write, for all $i \in \omega$ we have $sup(C_i)<\omega_1$.

In this case loop through limit values from $\omega$ to $\omega_1$ and mark whether they belong to $C_0$ or not. Mark the least upper bound of elements in $C_0$ as $a_0$ (this is first term of sequence). Do this again for $C_1$ and mark the sup of values in $C_1$ as $a_1$. if it turns out that $a_1 \le a_0$ then ignore $a_1$. Otherwise set the second term of sequence to $a_1$. Repeat this all the way $\omega$ number of times.

This gives a sequence for $\omega_1$. This leaves the possibility for scenario (2) which is:

**(2)** There exist some values $i \in \omega$ such that $sup(C_i)=\omega_1$

Specifically let's just assume that $sup(C_0)=\omega_1$. The definitions below can be easily generalised for any value $k \ne 0$.

Define a function $h^0_\alpha:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Denote the smallest element of $C_0$ as $p_0$. We define:
$$h^0_\alpha(x)=0 \quad for \,\,\, \alpha \le p_0$$

For $\alpha>p_0$ we have: $h^0_\alpha(x)=max\{f_\beta(x)\,|\, \beta<\alpha$ and $\beta \in C_0 \}$. Now the function $h^0_\alpha$ can only change countable number of times and, furthermore, there must be a point $N_0<\omega_1$ after which it stops changing. So I guess whenever we have $sup(C_0)=\omega_1$ such a value $N_0<\omega_1$ would always exist? If it doesn't exist, then we have a contradiction.

The consideration in the above paragraph applies to all values $k$ for which we have $sup(C_k)=\omega_1$. I also hope, if it is known, someone points to a reference for proof (or an argument) for the existence of $N_k$ whenever $sup(C_k)=\omega_1$.

Comment: @Peter None of that addresses the OP's actual question, which is where *their particular idea* breaks down.

Comment: It's unclear why you believe that $R$ must be computationally reducible to a function that dominates every element of $F$, or why this would give a contradiction.

Comment: It seems that you are attaching some sort of special value to your statement that "one can assign to each element of $\omega_1$ a sequence in some way" which is extremely vague.  As stated, that statement is totally trivial (why not assign the constant sequence $0$ to every element of $\omega_1$)?  I would suggest you clarify exactly what you mean by this statement.

Comment: @EricWofsey I will make a separate "Edit:" to the question along the line I was thinking about.

Comment: @SSequence Based on your comment, and hopefully anticipating your edit, I've refined my answer below. *(One moral, of a cardinal characteristic flavor, is that you're assuming the partial order of functions under domination is much simpler than it actually is.)*

Comment: Why not give this a proper title?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't think that it is a good question. That's why I guess not much interest for me in changing this kind of stuff too much. Also, I am not certain what would be a good title. You can change it if you want to.

Comment: I honestly can't tell what you are trying to explain in your edit.  What are you even trying to do in the two cases?  What is "a sequence for $\omega_1$"?

Comment: Are you claiming that the existence of such an $N$ at the end of the second case would give a contradiction?  If so, why is it a contradiction? I think you may be tacitly assuming something like $f_\alpha(x)<f_\beta(x)$ whenever $\alpha<\beta$, $\alpha,\beta\in C_n$, and $x\geq n$.  This definitely doesn't have to be true, since $\alpha,\beta\in C_n$ only tells you about how $f_\alpha$ and $f_\beta$ relate to $g$, not how $f_\alpha$ and $f_\beta$ relate to each other.

Comment: @EricWofsey Sorry if it wasn't clear enough. I should have been more careful (I didn't know it would cause confusion). By "sequence" I meant "fundamental sequence" ..... through out the post. No, I wasn't assuming that the existence of such an $N$ would give a contradiction. But rather that the *non-existence* of such an $N$ would give a contradiction. Just exactly how, I didn't add it because I am assuming such an $N$ would exist (in light of the answer/comments given). In case someone explains it doesn't, I will add one further (small this time) edit.

Comment: @EricWofsey *"I think you may be tacitly assuming something like $f_\alpha(x)<f_\beta(x)$ whenever $\alpha<\beta$, $\alpha,\beta\in C_n$, and $x\geq n$".* You are right that this doesn't have to be true. I am genuinely having difficulty identifying the point where I assumed it implicitly. Can you point the exact part in the *"Edit:"* where I did that?

Comment: No, I can't, because you didn't actually explain all the steps of your argument.  That was just my idle speculation about how you might be thinking a contradiction is reached in case (2).

Comment: @EricWofsey Well I tried my best to explain all steps well-enough (and in case it seems any point isn't explained well-enough, I can try to add more precision). But anyway, something that I should mention is that I wasn't assuming that a contradiction is reaching in (2) *unconditionally*. Of course not! I was assuming that a contradiction is reached *IF* a certain condition fails (the existence of $N$). So an answer to the question in "Edit:" would simply explain that why this condition never fails (*assuming* that all the other pieces in my description fit well). Hope that clarifies a bit.

Comment: @Deedlit Perhaps you can comment on some of the definitions and constructions? ... of course in case you have enough time to read through this (and it is a very long question). Because I think you might find them familiar (partly based on your answer to one of my overflow questions). Of course you don't have to comment on something which isn't your expertise. Just read through (1) the answer to the question and comments below it (2) and then later the *Edits* in order. There isn't much need to read the main body of question.

Comment: For example, (a) is the construction in scenario-1 of *Edit* correct (b) Does the description of $h$ in scenario-2 of *Edit* seems robust enough (c) Do the definitions of sequences and functions in *Edit3* look  good enough? (I think I need to check these). Similarly comments on any other aspects that might be within your expertise.

Comment: @Deedlit OK never mind. Sorry for bothering. To add some explanation, I think I might have been going about it from the wrong end anyway. I have thought of another method (which seems to be a better approach).

Comment: At this point the question has become largely unreadable; I would rewrite it so that it only reflects your argument as it currently stands. That said, l have the following immediate questions:

Comment: The most obvious problem is that your definition of $h_\alpha(x)$ seems problematic. I *think* you want each $h_\alpha$ to be a function into the naturals, but $h_\alpha(x)$ is defined as a supremum *(you write "maximum," but you shouldn't unless you can justify the existence of a maximum element)* over a set of natural numbers, and you give no argument that that set needs to always be finite.

Comment: There also seems to be a serious problem beginning with the paragraph "The collection of functions $\mathcal{F}$ was defined by Noah ..." and I think you've misunderstood my answer. Specifically you seem to be juggling between two contradictory statements. **The first** is what I called $(*)$, asserting the existence of a dominating family of size $\omega_1$. As I said in my answer, $(*)$ is not provable in ZFC *(I didn't claim that $(*)$ was true)*. (However, if you like we may assume it; since ZFC+$(*)$ doesn't prove CH, there's got to be another mistake.) But then things get weird: (cont'd)

Comment: You write "The question comes down to the following point: "does there exist a function $g$ such that $g$ (eventually) dominates every function in $\mathcal{F}$." Note that the answer to this point is *obviously "no,"* under the assumption on $\mathcal{F}$ above. So **the second** statement is, "Every $\omega_1$-size family of functions is dominated by some individual function" (thus justifying your consideration of the existence of a $g$ dominating every element of $\mathcal{F}$). But of course **the first statement and the second statement contradict each other**. (cont'd)

Comment: This is one point where clarity becomes an issue. The juggling between motivation and actual argument in the current version of your question leaves me uncertain as to whether you've actually *assumed* this contradiction in the argument you want to make. It's possible that this was all "flavor," and that ultimately this particular issue isn't really something relevant to your intuition. I think you need to completely rewrite this question: delete most of it, and only write your argument as it **currently** stands; until then, the answer to your title question is "we don't see an issue at all."

Comment: (In particular, remember that none of your writing will be lost: everything will be visible in the edit history, so you can simply begin your new question with something along the lines of "This question has significantly evolved over time in response to comments; see the edit history for its previous versions.")

Comment: @NoahSchweber Let me say that I really appreciate such a detailed response. Yes you are right that the question became too long. Alright I will just keep the most relevant parts (so it becomes easier to read). Secondly you are right that the function $h^0_\alpha$ (assuming $sup(C_0)=\omega_1$) is indeed from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. While I didn't justify it in detail, I am quite certain that my def. was correct. I think a (transfinite) induction argument could be used to prove this. At any rate, I don't think this approach is that useful because one of the important points it  (cont.)

Comment: comes down to is quite unintuitive (meaning it doesn't seem easy to see whether that point is right or not). Anyway, I have thought of another method which is much more direct and I am writing it in detail. So there might be a slight delay in the edit to the question.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Also I don't think I misunderstood any part of your answer in a fundamental way (ofc I don't understand the advanced stuff but that's not relevant here). 
But it seems you are right that I made a mistake in that sentence there (quite unfortunately that seems to have been source of unnecessary confusion). My apology for that. 
Let me be clear what I actually meant. Basically as you wrote that $(**)_1$ can be disproved in ZFC. What I was actually trying to show was that a certain plausibility argument shows that this $(**)_1$ *may* be correct. But in the end (cont.)

Comment: it comes down to a statement that seems very difficult for me to see as right or wrong directly. Once I edit, it will become clearer I think. The other approach I am looking at (thought of it yesterday) doesn't seem to come down to such an assumption (but ofc I need sometime to check where I am making a logical error .... I will post it only after checking it few times ..... at least on my part and then ask where I might be making a mistake). [sorry had to re-write the comments because of a really crucial typo]

Comment: @Deedlit  Can you take a look at PF? I posted an argument there, where I am having some trouble finding an issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you've written is correct, but it doesn't end in a contradiction.

Here's an example of how $N_0$ can exist - and indeed be small - without really doing anything *(I'm going to work with all ordinals, not just limit ordinals, since that's more natural - there's no reason in your current argument to restrict attention to limits)*:

- Let $g(x)=x+1$.
- For each $k\in\omega$, $f_k(x)=\min\{g(x)-1, k\}$.
- Let $f_\omega=floor(\ln(x+1))$.

Then we have $k\in C_0$ for $k\le\omega$. Moreover, note that the "$h$-sequence" has already stablized by step $\omega$: no matter how we continue the sequence of $f$s, we'll always have $$h_\alpha^0(x)=x$$ for $\alpha\ge\omega$. In your notation, this means $N_0=\omega$.

But this doesn't really do anything to constrain the sequence of $f$s going forward: there is still "lots of room" between $f_\omega$ and $g$. Basically, $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty,\alpha\in C_0}h_\alpha^0$ doesn't really capture much information.

(Also, your last sentence is incorrect: we could have $C_0$ be everything!)

Comment: I'm curious, why the downvote?

Comment: Yes, what you have written as highlighted statement is similar to what I was considering in the question. But it isn't clear to me why that statement would be considered false in set theory. This was indeed the main purpose of asking this question (now in retrospect, my question should have been much shorter). Suppose there was some function $g$ such that $g$ (eventually) dominates every function in $\mathcal{F}$. Shouldn't one be able to give a "definition" for a sequence for $\omega_1$ itself using the function $g$?

Comment: @SSequence No. Why does it seem like you should be able to? (You should clarify your question along the lines of your comment, since as written it is not clear at all that that's the issue you're asking about.)

Comment: I will add what I was thinking in an "Edit:" to the question (writing in comment would be far too confusing).

Comment: Edited the question...

Comment: Can you modify your Answer for an answer to the point raised in "Edit:". That would be very helpful. Of course if you think there is any ambiguity or lack of clarity there, just mention it. I will try my best to address it.

Comment: I feel the approach that I have considered here is less than ideal one. I have thought of another approach. Indeed I will post it ONLY after triple checking it (on the very least) .... otherwise ofc I won't be posting it at all.

Comment: @SSequence Sorry for the late reply. I've posted some comments below your question.

Comment: I removed a lot of the parts that weren't directly relevant to the question. The question is now mostly what I wrote in "Edit:" in the previous version. But maybe this decrease in length makes it easier to understand the point of question.

Comment: Your example was very reflective along the line this question was asked. In your example, does $f_{\omega \cdot 2} \in C_0$? For example, for that to be true, it seems that it would have to be the case that $g(x)>f_{\omega \cdot 2}(x)$ for all $x \ge 0$.

Comment: @SSequence Whoops, good catch, I wrote too fast. Rolling back until I can fix ...

Comment: No problem. At least it means someone reads, what one writes, carefully.

Comment: Ok, I read way too quickly. We definitely have $h_\alpha^0(x)<g(x)$ whenever $\alpha\in C_0$. What contradiction do you want to draw from the existence of $N_0$?

Comment: Also, your last sentence is unjustified: we could have $C_i=\emptyset$ for all $i\not=0$. Everything could like in $C_0$.

Comment: @SSequence Fixed. The point is that the existence of $N_0$ actually doesn't tell us very much, so - while your argument for its existence is correct - it doesn't take us towards the larger contradiction that you want.

Comment: Let's assume for example that $sup(C_0)=\omega_1$. I wasn't arguing for the existence of $N_0$ (*assuming* $sup(C_0)=\omega_1$).
 I was arguing that (1)If  $N_0$ exists then there isn't any issue (2) If $N_0$ doesn't exist then we can arrive at a contradiction ........... What 
 I was trying to say was that it isn't clear at all to me why (1) should be true. In your example, as you rightly said that $N_0=\omega$. Now in your example, just for the sake of supposition, also assume that all the $C_i$'s are are empty for $i>0$. As a set theorist, I suppose you find it perfectly natural. (cont)

Comment: At any rate, as I mentioned that I am working on another argument that comes from a different angle. More importantly, it doesn't seem to any invoke any intuition/assumption of this kind (or lack of it), but is much more direct along the lines of a proof.  I will probably post it in a few weeks time (unless I find a mistake myself, in which case I won't post of course).

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the detailed answers and careful reading of the thread. Learning that $(**)_1$ is false in ZFC was very educational and important fact for me.

Comment: @SSequence  "The last sentence should probably start with something along the lines of "Assuming that the Ci's are all non-empty,....." " No, we can basically do whatever we want: e.g. we could have all $C_i$s nonempty, $C_{2i}$ cofinal in $\omega_1$ for each $i$, and $C_{2i+1}$ not cofinal in $\omega_1$ for each $i$. But regardless, it sounds like this specific question is resolved?

Comment: Oh my bad! .....sorry. I had realised this. And I deleted the comment almost the same second you wrote the message! I will remove that incorrect statement from the question. Yes, this specific problem is definitively resolved.